# How to clone models in Ruby on Rails/ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create many copies of a message to users:

```
users.each do |user|
  new_message = message.clone
  new_message.to = user
  new_message.save!
end
```

However, this doesn't work after the 1st user. Here's part of the error message:

```
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "messages" ("content", "to_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["content", "abc"], ["to_id", 1]]
   (2.5ms)  commit transaction
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "messages" ("content", "id", "to_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["content", "abc"], ["id", 6], ["to_id", 2]]
SQLite3::ConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique: INSERT INTO "messages" ("content", "id", "to_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?)
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 130.1ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::ConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique: INSERT INTO "messages" ("content", "id", "to_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?)):
```

As you can see, the problem is that the 2nd time the loop runs, `message.clone` must contain the `id` of the previous `new_message`.

What is the proper way to clone message records for many users? I can, of course, manually copy each attribute (I have a ***lot*** more than just `content` and `to_id`) into a fresh new `Message` object. But I'd like to know if there's a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`dup`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-dup), with which the `id`, `created_at` and `updated_at` are set to `nil`.  This will ensure that Primary Key exception is not thrown, however if there are other unique validations, they will fail.  You'd have to handle them separately.

```
users.each do |user|
  new_message = message.dup
  new_message.to = user
  new_message.save!
end
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Why would `clone` behave this way though? Seems odd that the original object would end up with fields from the cloned object.